# Any reason NOT to enable WSDL Caching for SOAP in Magento?

Tags: magento, caching, soap

Can anyone see a reason ***not*** to enable the WSDL Cache in Magento?

I have an EPOS system that is periodically talking to Magento from outside the network. When it does this, the site suffers from a huge dip in speed, as it appears to struggle with the SOAP API. Even hitting the site with an https request like this:

https://[site-url]/api/v2_soap?wsdl=1

The response can be up to 10 seconds. Sometimes, when lots of these requests are made, the server grinds to a halt, and there are many sleeping connections left in the MySQL database.

On checking whether Magento is configured for WSDL caching, I notice that it isn't. I didn't develop the site, however, and I'm wondering if there are any legitimate reasons ***not*** to enable this feature?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is obvious: **for debugging**.

I've experienced an issue (running Magento and PHP-FPM) where the WSDL cache became corrupted during a huge spike in traffic, which resulted in 503 errors whenever a SoapClient was constructed. That cache didn't clear through restarts of PHP-FPM, Apache, and the machine. Clearing the SOAP cache solved the problem, but it took some time to debug, and cache issues tend to be extra maddening.

I should say that I have no idea if this is a common issue, but the WSDL cache is a component that, like any component, can break.